# MySQL Group By: ignore when any entry does not match a condition

Tags: mysql

I want to group by type, but should ignore when there's any entry with the status 1.

I tried to do it with `IF`, but failed.
After a lot of search, I didn't find anything like that, so I decided to ask your help.

---

Table Example:

```
|  id   -  status   -   type   |
|   1   -    0      -     1    |
|   2   -    2      -     1    |
|   3   -    1      -     1    | - Should ignore all group - status 1.
|   4   -    3      -     2    |
|   5   -    0      -     2    |
|   6   -    3      -     2    |
|   7   -    2      -     3    |
|   8   -    0      -     3    |
|   9   -    3      -     3    |
|   9   -    2      -     3    |
|   10  -    1      -     4    | - Should ignore all group - status 1.
|   11  -    2      -     4    |
|   12  -    0      -     4    |
|   13  -    1      -     4    | - Should ignore all group - status 1.
```

---

Code:

```
SELECT type, count(*) FROM table GROUP BY type;
```

---

What I get:

```
|  type   -  count(*) |
|   1     -     3     |
|   2     -     3     |
|   3     -     4     |
|   4     -     4     |
```

---

What I want:
(type 1 and 4 should be ignored, because have entries with status 1)

```
|  type   -  count(*) |
|   2     -     3     |
|   3     -     4     |
```

Comment: @Strawberry I did not understand your concept. Can you answer with the query based on the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If status is either one or zero, it should be enough to add a HAVING clause to the GROUP BY:-

```
HAVING MAX(status)=0
```

In the case that you have more values, I suggest using two inline queries like this:-

```
SELECT t1.type,t1.count
from
(
  select type, count(*) as count
  FROM Example 
  GROUP BY type
) t1
left outer join
(
  SELECT type 
  FROM Example
  where Status=1
  GROUP BY type
) t2
on t1.type=t2.type
where t2.type is null;
```

Giving results

```
2 | 3
3 | 4
```

as expected.

There are possible variations on this like using 'SELECT DISTINCT' in the second inline query instead of GROUP BY.

Comment: It works fine when status can only be 0 and 1 (just like in my question), but whats your idea when can have more options like 0, 1, 2, 3 (and would just exclude when 1)?

Comment: It would involve a join and be a bit more complicated. Sorry I'll have to get back to later on that one because just leaving the building!

Comment: Have posted a revised answer.

Comment: Far too much query here.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.type
            , COUNT(*) total
         FROM my_table x 
        GROUP 
           BY type
     ) a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table b 
    ON b.type = a.type 
   AND b.status = 1 
 WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```